# Opening up a link in a new tab in Firefox doesn't show address

Tags: firefox

Sometimes for some reason, connection to a new link/address takes a long time to establish. In Firefox 11.0, the address bar will keep showing "about:blank". I take this as normal, and let me know if it isn't.

If the connection is stopped for some reason, I will not be able to find out the address that I was trying to connect to.

I wonder how to find out that address, both before and after the connection is stopped at "about:blank"?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Interesting, I tried middle-click to open link in new tab (one that I knew is going to take few seconds) and immediately switched to it and stopped/cancelled it. The address bar shows the target url just fine with a blank page. You might want to provide some more info like firefox version and the URL (**only if you are OK with it**) and how the link is launched in a new tab - is it a plugin ? middle click (in which case you can get the target by hovering mouse over the link, most of the time) ?

Comment: @Anil: (1) I don't know why in some cases there are addresses in address bar, and in other cases there ain't. (2) For example, first open this webpage http://bookfi.org/s/?q=Kleene+Introduction+to+metamathematics&t=0 . Then click "Скачать (DJVU)" under the first item "Introduction to Metamathematics (Bibliotheca Mathematica) (Bibliotheca Mathematica)
S.C. Kleene". It will open a new tab to connect to the file, but there is no address in the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the 'web console' to see whats going on. Say, in case of the URL you mentioned in the comments, use middle click to open the book specific page in another tab. Now, while viewing the book specific page, enable the console in firefox (`Tools->Web Developer->Web Console`) and now click the download link. It should show the URLs that are being used. It would look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! If I have already opened the link to the file in another tab, and closed the webpage where my link was from, how can I find out the link the current "about:blank" tab is trying to connect to?

Comment: Well, if we consider a situation where we can't restart the query *at all*, I don't know of any way to get that info. Otherwise, you've got the web-history (to retry) and external tools (like wireshark; to snoop everything).